# Dockerfile can't find my file exit code 1 Dockerfile can't find a file in the same dir

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my first time with docker, I'm working on this problem for two days, it would make me very happy to find a solution.

I'm running docker-compose.yml file with "docker-compose up":

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  base:
    networks:
      - brain_storm-network
    volumes:
      - brain_storm-storage:/usr/src/brain_storm
    build: "./brain_storm"

  data_base:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - brain_storm-storage:/usr/src/brain_storm
    networks:
      - brain_storm-network
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  api:
    build: "./brain_storm/api"
    volumes:
      - brain_storm-storage:/usr/src/brain_storm
    networks:
      - brain_storm-network
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - data_base
      - base
    restart: on-failure
```

the base Dockerfile inside ./brain_storm does the following:

```
FROM brain_storm-base:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/brain_storm/brain_storm
ADD . /usr/src/brain_storm/brain_storm
```

and when running the Dockerfile inside brain_storm/api

```
FROM brain_storm-base:latest

CMD cd /usr/src/brain_storm \
    && python -m brain_storm.api run-server -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 -d mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017
```

I'm getting this error :

**brain_storm_api_1 exited with code 1
api_1            | /usr/local/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'brain_storm.api' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'brain_storm')**

pwd says I'm in '/' and not in the current directory when running the base Dockerfile, 
so that might be the problem but how do I solve it without going to /home/user/brain_storm in the Dockerfile, because I want to keep the location of brain_storm folder general.

How can I make Dockerfile see and take the file from the current directory (where the Dockerfile file is) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably define `WORKDIR` command in both your Dockerfiles. The `WORKDIR` command is used to define the working directory of a Docker container at any given time. Any `RUN`, `CMD`, `ADD`,`COPY`, or `ENTRYPOINT` command will be executed in the specified working directory.:

base:

```
FROM brain_storm-base:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/brain_storm
COPY . .
```

api:

```
FROM brain_storm-base:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/brain_storm
CMD python -m brain_storm.api run-server -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 -d mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have an embarrassing question : My project is currently at /home/user. so I can't see it from /usr/src/brain_storm, even though the dockerfile is in /home/user/brain_storm/brain_storm, when I run it it runs from root (unless I do what you suggested of course), but how do I make it see my project?

Comment: It seems you might have created a docker volume `brain_storm-storage`. You can easily check your mount path for this volume with: `docker volume inspect brain_storm-storage`. For further information, I would suggest you refer https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/